# Architecture definition

Tags: architecture, definition, concept

As I understand MVC,MVVM,SOA,Onion are an architecture, but I really got confused. I think this is not correct that I assume all of them define as the same Architecture concept. I want to know what is true about architecture...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is very broad and it does not have a commonly accepted answer. It will probably be downvoted and closed sooner or later. I will try to answer it anyway.

An architecture is a property of a specific piece of software. MVC, MVVM and SOA are architectural patterns that can be implemented by different pieces of software.

There are many definitions of architecture. My favourite one is:

"The things that are important and will be hard to change later."

This definition has been phrased by Martin Fowler but I am not sure if he was the first to come up with it. I like it because it makes clear that it is a bad thing to have more architecture than absolutely required, especially in a world where changes are likely to occur and the future is hard to predict.

Answer (score 1):

IASA Defines architecture as:

"IT architecture is the art and science of designing and delivering valuable technology strategy."

Tom Gilb defines it as:

"The ‘architecture’ is the set of entities that in fact exist and Impact a set of system Attributes directly, or indirectly, by constraining, or influencing, related Engineering decisions."

Basically they are the big decisions that should be made upfront to ensure that you can deliver. As Frank says they are hard to change later.